# Global function into app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implment Auth with roles in my Ionic project. The problem is that the project that I'm following is old so the project structure has too much differences.

This is the project that I'm following:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Mvrte4?p=preview

This project has the following script:

**globalFunctions.js**

```
/**
 * Contains functions that are added to the root AngularJs scope.
 */
angular.module('loginApp').run(function($rootScope, $state, Auth, AUTH_EVENTS) {

//before each state change, check if the user is logged in
//and authorized to move onto the next state
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;
    if (!Auth.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        // user is not allowed
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
      } else {
        // user is not logged in
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
      }
    }
  });

/* To show current active state on menu */
$rootScope.getClass = function(path) {
    if ($state.current.name == path) {
        return "active";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

$rootScope.logout = function(){
    Auth.logout();
};

});
```

So... In my project I don't have a file like the script above, but I have:
 **app.js**

```
angular.module('restaurant', [
'ionic',
'ionic.service.core',
'ionic.service.push',

'ngCordova',
'ionic-toast',
'LocalStorageModule',
'firebase',

'config',
'restaurant.restaurant-cart',
'restaurant.restaurant-delivery',
'restaurant.categories',
'restaurant.products',
'restaurant.news',
'restaurant.map',
'restaurant.home',
'restaurant.cancha',
'restaurant.ultimasoperaciones',
'restaurant.push',
'restaurant.menu',
'restaurant.listanegra',
'restaurant.login',
'restaurant.agenda',
'restaurant.contacto',
'restaurant.infocancha',
'restaurant.wordpress',
'restaurant.drupal',
'restaurant.favorites',
'gMaps'
])

.value('_', window._)

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
});
})

.config(function($urlRouterProvider) {
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
});
```

**How can I merge globalFunctions.js with my script app.js?
Shall I need to make another script? I want to keep my project structure.**

Thanks!

Comment: Create a `utilities` Angular service and put all the `globalFunctions` functions in it.

Comment: Well i think you need to take angular.module as common between this two, and include both file in your view(index.html or something else). That would be easy then you don't need to merge this manually.

Comment: Isn't it enough to change `angular.module('loginApp')` with `angular.module('restaurant')`? You can have multiple run functions in one app...

Comment: The problem is structure of the project. May be I have put those files into another script

Answer (score 0):

you can copy those functions to app.js. there are three spaces where you may paste your globle functions as per your requirment.
1) inside .run
2) inside .config
3) outside those both

dont forget dependency